# Input type to have width of 100% and be inside parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a form with input for an email and password and some other buttons.

html:

```
<div  id="login-form">
<form>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email_phone">
    <br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password">
    <br>
    <button id="login-submit">Submit</button>
    <br>
    <button id="login-forgot">Forgot Password</button>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<center>
    <p>Don't have an account?</p>
</center>
<button id="create-new-account">Create Account Now</button>
</div>
```

I need the input and buttons to be 100% width of the parent. **And** have a padding of 10px.

```
#login-form input[type=email], #login-form input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14pt;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

#login-form button {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14pt;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Then the problem starts with the input width. All the buttons are inside the parent element, but the input box cross the parent div. Like this:

[image]

[demo at Codepen](http://codepen.io/Kakar/pen/KzGOVp).

**How do I keep the input box inside the parent div and have a width of 100% and still have padding**?

Comment: does the parent div have padding? or just try  box-sizing: border-box and see if that works because you have added padding and if box-size is not border-box then it will be added to the element

Comment: No it doesnt have padding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is with the input paddings. To fix it add box-sizing property to your input fields:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

I just tested it in your codepen, seems like the result you want.

Comment: Yes. This is the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

give div width 100% and then change input field width

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the padding in the input elements. It is set to ten, causing it to have to expand past the edge of the parent element. Possible solutions include just removing the padding or decreasing the width so it fits nicely inside.

Comment: But removing the padding just looks ugly as the text start right from the border. Is it possible to have the padding and keep the input inside the parent div?

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code inside your style file**

```
*,
 ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```